# Infinite loop problem with belongsToMany relationships in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I'm running into an infinite loop problem. I have two objects, Group and Issue. They have a many-to-many relationship so each group can have many issues and each issue can belong to many groups.

When I call the GroupResource, I want it to load in each group's issues and when I call the IssueResource, I want it to load each issue's groups. The problem I'm running into is that this creates a loop as Group calls Issue, Issue calls Group and so on.

I've dug into articles and documentation which suggest that I should be using the whenLoaded function. But the examples I see say that you only use this for either Group or for Issue. Not for both and that's what breaks the loop. But doesn't that prevent me from being able to achieve the functionality I'm looking for?

What am I missing?

Below are the relevant lines. Without the whenLoaded functions, I get an infinite loop. With them, the data doesn't get returned.

**Group.php**

```
public function issues() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Issue::class)->orderBy('issue.number');
}
```

**Issue.php**

```
public function groups() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Group::class);
}
```

**GroupResource.php**

```
public function toArray(Request $request): array
{
    return [
        'issues' => IssueResource::collection($this->whenLoaded('issues'))
    ];
}
```

**IssueResource.php**

```
public function toArray(Request $request): array
{
    return [
        'groups' => GroupResource::collection($this->whenLoaded('groups'))
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

toArray function always runs when you load model. When you load Issue model it loads Group model and then when you call Issue model toArray function loads Issue model.
So it is obvious that the infinite loop occurs
I suggest you not to use of toArray function
You can use of append or with in model. But take care they are dangerous too.
It is better to load them everywhere you want.
Good luck